# CKEDITOR How to disable the element information dialog

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I have searched for this on the web and I can't find it. When I hover the mouse on a element A  element information dialog is showed:

[image]

How can I disable the element information dialog/popup or whatever it is?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check if there's [`devtools`](http://ckeditor.com/addon/devtools) plugin loaded in your configuration. You can either exclude it from [`config.plugins`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-plugins) or add it to [`config.removePlugins`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-removePlugins).

Comment: I think that @sirwilliam has mistakenly built CKEditor package with devtools plugin and may want to completely remove it from the build.